# regex email valid despite missing dot extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I've this regex for email

```
^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*(\+[a-z0-9-]+)?@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$
```

my test case is `johnd@c` but it returned true. What's wrong here?

https://codesandbox.io/s/regex-forked-h7r6wk?file=/src/index.js:180-187

Comment: The quantifier `*` means “0 or more times”. The quantifier `+` means “1 or more times”. Your regex correctly matches the pattern `\.[a-z0-9-]+` zero times after the `c`. Also, please note that this regex is unnecessarily restrictive; it’s not standards compliant.

Comment: To provide an example, you can try `/^\w+((-\w+)|(\.\w+))*\@[A-Za-z0-9]+((\.|-)[A-Za -z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z]+$/`

Comment: @Ian john+james@gmail.com this have to be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*(\+[a-z0-9-]+)?@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)$
```

Please note that your regex may not perfectly fit all cases nor match all cases in [RFC 5322](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt).